# My javascript array keeps getting overwritten when trying to add a new object

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript

I am using nativescript core with plain javascript. But I do not think this is where the issue lies. The basis of my problem is I am trying to add a new object to a global array and when I do, my previous data keeps getting overwritten with the new object.

I have tried a normal array.push({data}) and the ES6 spread [...array, {data}]. Both of these methods ended up overwriting the previous data in the array with the new object.

record-page.js

```
// import statements

// variables

// 'global' array of markers. 
var markers = [];

// this function opens a custom modal 
function addObsticalTapped(args) {

  // close the popup
  var page = args.object.page;
  var popup = page.getViewById("trailNotesPopup");
  isShown = false;

  popup.animate({
    translate: {
      x: 0,
      y: 500
    },
    duration: 300,
    curve: enums.AnimationCurve.easeInOut
  });

  var mainView = args.object;
  var context = {};

  geolocation
    .getCurrentLocation({
      desiredAccuracy: Accuracy.high
    })
    .then(loc => {
      curLoc = loc;
    });


  mainView.showModal(obsticalModal, context, addObsticalIcon, false);
}
exports.addObsticalTapped = addObsticalTapped;

// callback function when the modal is closed
function addObsticalIcon(didConfirm, data) {
  if (didConfirm) {
    // this is where the problem is, the markers array is being overwritten
    //     when adding another marker
    markers = [...markers, {
      type: "obstical",
      location: {
        lat: curLoc.latitude,
        lng: curLoc.longitude
      },
      data: data,
      trail_id: ""
    }];

    map.addMarkers([{
      id: markerID,
      lat: curLoc.latitude,
      lng: curLoc.longitude,
      //icon: "res://obstical_icon"
      iconPath: "./icons/obstical_icon_marker.png"
    }]);
    markerID++;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(markers));
  } else {
    console.log("closed");
  }
}
```

obstical-modal.js

```
function onShownModally(args) {
    const context = args.context;
    closeCallback = args.closeCallback;
    const page = args.object;

    vm = observableModule.fromObject(context);
    vm.set("oneSelected", oneSelected ? oneOn : oneOff);
    vm.set("threeSelected", threeSelected ? threeOn : threeOff);
    vm.set("sixSelected", sixSelected ? sixOn : sixOff);
    vm.set("nineSelected", nineSelected ? nineOn : nineOff);

    page.bindingContext = vm;
}
exports.onShownModally = onShownModally;

function onCancel(args) {
    closeCallback(false, {});
}
exports.onCancel = onCancel;

function onSubmit(args) {
    var page = args.object.page;
    var textField = page.getViewById("info");
    data.info = textField.text;
    closeCallback(true, data);
}
exports.onSubmit = onSubmit;
```

What I expect to happen:
obstacle one has a difficulty of 1 and info of "hello world"
then add it to the array and the array is correct. 
Then I add another obstacle with a difficulty of 3 and info of "hello code"
When this gets added to the array, the array then looks like:

```
[{"type":"obstical","data":{"difficulty":3,"info":"hello code"}},{"type":"obstical","data":{"difficulty":3,"info":"hello code"}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to put this as a comment but wanted to show you an example of what I believe you are doing wrong by writing some simplified version of the code you have.

```
const data = {
  difficulty: '1',
  info: 'hello code',
};

const markers = [];

markers.push({
  type: 'obstical',
  data: data,
});

// Here is the problem. The problem is not related to the array adding
data.difficulty = '3';

markers.push({
  type: 'obstical',
  data: data,
});
```

The issue has nothing to do with how you add to the array but that you are mutating your original data object. The solution would be the following

```
const data = {
  difficulty: '1',
  info: 'hello code',
};

const markers = [];

markers.push({
  type: 'obstical',
  data: data,
});

// create a new object instead of mutating the existing one
const newData = {
  ...data,
  difficulty: '3',
};

markers.push({
  type: 'obstical',
  data: newData,
});
```

Comment: You should note that this is a shallow spread; any objects contained within `data` would be referenced and any changes to those objects would reflect in both.